# How to avoid error converting Cypher Query into NetworkX Graph in Python

Tags: py2neo

I want to convert the results of a Neo4j Data into Graph in Python using py2Neo.

The below link provides a detail program code:

http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-jupyter/hello-world.html

```
import networkx as nx

%matplotlib inline
results = %cypher MATCH p = (:Person)-[:LIKES]->(:Drink) RETURN p
g = results.get_graph()

nx.draw(g)
```

The get_graph function throws an error as:

> TypeError: error() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given).

The function expects two arguments. But I do not understand what is wrong with the Cypher Query? Thank you.